# aggregate several software modules into one package

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Is it possible to aggregate several software modules (each having its own bitbake recipe) into one single package? (eg: a package that groups openssl+libnss+curl)

How should I write the recipe? May the `PACKAGES` keyword help?

I looked at packagegroup, that does not do this.

EDIT: My purpose is to create custom packages for a minimal embedded OS, not the regular rpm or deb, but squashfs based packages.

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what packagegroups do. If you want to "merge" packages - you'll need to merge recipes and I have no idea why would anyone be interested in creating such a Frankenstein.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a useful feature: you might want to explain the underlying reason for wanting this -- maybe there is another way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It "could" look like this `my_package.bb`

```
DESCRIPTION = "My package"

inherit packagegroup

DEPENDS_${PN}= "\
    openssl \
    libnss \
    curl \
"
```

Then just include the package where you need it, e.g., `my_super_package.bb`

```
DESCRIPTION = "My super package"

inherit packagegroup

DEPENDS_${PN} = "my_package"
```

Please have a look at this post: https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2014-July/020412.html